# Unusual value for layout_weight for a view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I was going through [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaEffects/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_media_effects.xml)  for media effects in Android samples for API level 23 and found an unusual value (0.93) being assigned to layout_weight for one of the views contained in a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/effectsview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.93"/>
```

Since the layout is not having any other childviews other than android.opengl.GLSurfaceView , does this value (or android:layout_weight itself) has any significance? I tried to change this value randomly and as expected it did not have any impact on layout.

Edit : Added sample code link

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any more views with weigths nothing would happen. It's depends on it what `android:layout_weight` exactly does:

> With `layout_weight` you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a `MapView` and a `table` which should show some
>   additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the
>   screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the
>   `layout_weight` of the `map` to 3 and the `layout_weight` of the table
>   to 1.
>
> To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px.

Read this: [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

So according to your question if you don't have more views with weight, you can also delete this line of code.

EDIT: Thanks for the link. Now I know the reason of this attribute. 
Mysterious `fragment_media_effects.xml` layout file might be already inherited in `activity_main.xml`, where two others views has also weights. If I am right the value of this view should change, not in Layout Editor, but when you open an app with this fragment.

Comment: Yes , Im aware of the weight concept , but as the google sdk sample is having this code , I am wondering is there any hidden thing here.

Comment: I don't know on which sample are talking about (link would be very appreciated), but maybe when they changing the layout they forgot to delete this line

Comment: Added link for clarity , yes might be the case.

Comment: But I dont think the value changes , as android:layout_weight is defined inside fragment_media_effects.xml , and this fragment will be placed as a whole in activity_main.xml with it almost occupying 2/3 of layout.

Comment: change value - let's say to 20 and open the app. Thats all